# How to remove pipe symbol in Wordpress Tags under Post Menu

Tags: wordpress, tags, pipe, posts

i'v found an issue of title which shows extra pipe symbol which is not manually written in "Edit Tag" section on one of my website [pharmadesiccant](http://pharmadesiccants.com/tag/fibre-coils/). I just want to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to install WordPress SEO or All-In-One SEO so you can redefine the page title (without the | ).

Comment: Thanks Mr Mohammed Salah Eldowy, Problem has been resolved.